# Why is http://teststackoverflow.com/ in an iframe below Meta's footer?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, footer

I was just browsing Meta Stack Overflow, when I found this `<iframe>` hiding below the footer:

> [image]

Could someone explain why http://teststackoverflow.com/ needs to be embedded at the bottom of the page?

Comment: are you sure it's not your script that added it? I'm on mobile, but I'm sure I haven't seen this before.

Comment: It's all explained if you followed that link. @JanDvorak it says they add it to <1% of requests

Comment: no this is not my script, I was just browsing election Q&A page and even I got surprise to see a iframe in footer.

Comment: They're doing some performance testing, which requires a new domain name, or something like that. Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221591/cookies-and-javascript-for-teststackoverflow-com-legitimate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the website: http://teststackoverflow.com/

it says :

> You may have arrived here from looking at our iframe, welcome! We are
> not adding this extra hit to every request, but less than 1% of the
> requests to our network.
>
> The intent is to keep ay eye on performance
> and evaluate infrastructure changes and the impact they have.