# What is the purpose of the "this page" link in the teststackoverflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, javascript

When reading this [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221591/cookies-and-javascript-for-teststackoverflow-com-legitimate), I came to know about [teststackoverflow](http://teststackoverflow.com/).

In this page, there is a link named as **this page**, when clicking on that it didn't respond any. Inspect on the element the code was written as `<a href="javascript:;" ...`.

There was some function was written on that link and it was removed or the link is for any other purpose?

Screenshot for reference:

[image: What is this link in the teststackoverflow]